# Insufficient memory error in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Due to a large amount of data (more than 2,000,000 entries in a collection), Excel terminates my VBA program with an "Insufficient memory error" (code 7). I know that VBA is not the right language to handle so many data, but is there a way to increase the memory that Excel uses to run a VBA program? I precise it's not a stack overflow, the number of stack calls are limited to 10.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 4):

Depends what Excel version you are using. Versions earlier than Excel 2007 tend to have quite restricted memory capacity. 
32-bit Excel 2007 and later in theory can use a total of up to 2GB but in practice its often hard to get more than about 512MB for VBA. 
64-bit Excel 2010 and later are much better: I have successfully used up to 4 Gigabytes of VBA memory.
Its possible that using a Dictionary rather than a Collection will be somewhat more memory efficient, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Charles, in reading your answer you answered a question that was plaguing me for months now... Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Charles, these figures are very interesting to know! For my part, I'm using Excel 2007 on a Vista 64-bit OS. About dictionaries, you're right, but the issue is that they require the use of a key each time you add an element, which is not always relevant in my case. When thinking of decreasing memory usage, I found out that many elements were similar in my collection. In C++, I could store pointers to the same string. But how could I do that in VBA?

Comment: I would not advise trying to implement a string pool in VBA, but you could always use the XLL interface to get to C++

Comment: I didn't know about XLL and can't find much information about it. If I rewrite the code in C++, it will certainly go faster, but won't I still be subject to Excel memory limitations? I don't know how Windows manages the memory of a process calling another process.